# How to specify credentials for http_archive *within* the workspace?

Tags: bazel

I would like to specify credentials for a single URL in `http_archive`, using a netrc file contained in my workspace.  I have tried the following without success:

1. I have tried to specify the "userinfo" part of my URL like `http://<user>:<password>@host/path` just to get an authentication error.
2. I have tinkered with the `netrc` attribute of `http_archive`, but I can only see, how to use absolute pathnames there; I would prefer to include the netrc in my workspace.

Do I have to write my own repository rule or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I have created my own repository rule because I could not find a simple alternative.  That went well, but comprehensive documentation for `repository_ctx.download_and_extract` is lacking, so it turned out to be trial and error ;-).

Update: The additional repository rule that I have created is neither generic nor elegant, but I am using it now since several years across different Artifactory instances.  We have a generic username / password combination for read-only access to Artifactory, so I have just hardcoded the credentials in my `.bzl` file.  The rule looks like:

```
load(
    "@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:utils.bzl",
    "update_attrs",
    "workspace_and_buildfile",
)

_artifactory_archive_attrs = {
    "archive": attr.string(
        mandatory = True,
    ),
    "path": attr.string(
        default = "",
    ),
    "repo_name": attr.string(
        default = "project-name",
    ),
    "base_dir": attr.string(
        default = "artifactory",
    ),
    "host": attr.string(
        default = "artifactory.foobar.org:8082",
    ),
    "urlscheme": attr.string(
        default = "https",
    ),
    "login": attr.string(
        default = "username",
    ),
    "password": attr.string(
        default = "password",
    ),
    "build_file": attr.label(
        allow_single_file = True,
    ),
    "build_file_content": attr.string(),
    "workspace_file": attr.label(
        allow_single_file = True,
    ),
    "workspace_file_content": attr.string(),
    "sha256": attr.string(),
    "strip_prefix": attr.string(),
}

def _artifactory_archive_impl(rctx):
    base_url = rctx.attr.urlscheme + "://" + rctx.attr.host
    url = "/".join(
        [
            base_url,
            rctx.attr.base_dir,
            rctx.attr.repo_name,
            rctx.attr.path,
            rctx.attr.archive,
        ],
    )
    auth = {}
    auth[url] = {
        "type": "basic",
        "login": rctx.attr.login,
        "password": rctx.attr.password,
    }

    download_info = rctx.download_and_extract(
        [url],
        "",
        rctx.attr.sha256,
        "",
        rctx.attr.strip_prefix,
        canonical_id = "",
        auth = auth,
    )

    # print("Downloading {} from artifactory.".format(url))
    workspace_and_buildfile(rctx)

    return update_attrs(
        rctx.attr,
        _artifactory_archive_attrs.keys(),
        {"sha256": download_info.sha256},
    )

artifactory_archive = repository_rule(
    implementation = _artifactory_archive_impl,
    attrs = _artifactory_archive_attrs,
)
```

Comment: Would you please explain in more detail how you achieved it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [PR](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/9388/files#diff-0a0d5a6b64e11b6bc5bab80ad3a90003) named "Readd support for authentication and .netrc". It seems to contain a improved version of the `http_archive` that supports `.netrc` files.

```
def _http_archive_impl(ctx):
    ...
    "netrc": attr.string(
        doc = "Location of the .netrc file to use for authentication",
    ),
    ...
```

I do not know the current status of this feature - maybe its already part of the newest Bazel version (at the time of writing this post 3.4.1)

Comment: It's been briefly there in the initial 0.29 and then re-added with 1.1... So yes, as of quite a while it's available. However, for quite a while **not** on Windows hosts if that was the question. I've seen that in master some time ago and I am not entirely sure it's in a current release (commit `3c89a910ad1c59160ba4058c47b6752ce9e7efb6`, so 3.1 it seems).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I should have mentioned that I am using 3.4.1 from the beginning.  Authentication works as expected, when I am providing `$HOME/.netrc`; what I cannot figure out is, how to add `my.netrc` to my repository and provide it to `http_archive` from there.

Comment: [`http_archive`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive) has `netrc` attribute: "String; optional; Location of the .netrc file to use for authentication" which is using [`repo_ctx`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#read) to get the file (but being a repo rule, beware of the labels I guess).

Comment: @Ondrey: "beware of the labels": Could you elaborate? How do I specify a file inside the workspace?